# How to test XELement and its child elements?

Tags: fluent-assertions

I have a sample Xml code snippet

```
<modification name="givenName" operation="add" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:DSML:2:0:core">
    <value>Changed name</value>
</modification>
```

The xml is loaded to my XElement, and I used

```
        XElement xml = ...to load xml above...;
        xml.Should().HaveAttribute("name", "givenName")
            .And.HaveAttribute("operation", "add")
            .And.HaveAttribute("xmlns", "urn:oasis:names:tc:DSML:2:0:core")
            .And.HaveElement("value");
```

to test my code, the attributes testing are all passed, but the element testing (the last condition) fails.

Anyone can point out what is wrong with my code?

And how can I test the Xml has an element named "value" and its value is "Changed name"?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that the `XName` of the element isn't just `value` - it's `value` *with a namespace*. Presumably `HaveElement` is namespace-aware. Try this:

```
XElement xml = ...to load xml above...;
XNamespace ns = "urn:oasis:names:tc:DSML:2:0:core";
xml.Should().HaveAttribute("name", "givenName")
    .And.HaveAttribute("operation", "add")
    .And.HaveAttribute("xmlns", "urn:oasis:names:tc:DSML:2:0:core")
    .And.HaveElement(ns + "value");
```

The last line checks whether it's got the *namespace-qualified* element.

Comment: Good catch, I have to include namespace. However I have to change the code a bit `And.HaveElement((ns + "value").ToString())` otherwise it won't compile.

Comment: Any clue how can I test <value> element's value is "Changed name"?

Comment: @hardywang: Urgh - it doesn't take an XName? That sucks as an API :(

Comment: @hardywang: No idea about checking the value, I'm afraid - I've never used the fluent assertions library.

Comment: We'll gonna look at it in the next version of Fluent Assertions.

Comment: @DennisDoomen: The value part, or taking an `XName` as the input for `HaveElement`, `HaveAttribute` etc? The latter feels like it should be a no-brainer to me :)

Comment: Both. But we're in the process of finalizing a big release with a beta, so we'll have to freeze this for a few weeks.

Answer (score 2):

It's going to be part of Fluent Assertions 2.1. If you can't wait you can get it through the Git repository